# Facebook login - invalid access token

Tags: php, facebook-login

All of a sudden the facebook login on my web page stopped working - it returns message `invalid access token`. Some month ago it worked well. Can you please help? I use php as follows:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(

  'appId'  => 'xxx',

  'secret' => 'xxx',

));



$userfb = $facebook->getUser();

if ($userfb) {

    try { 

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');



    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

        $userfb = null;

    }

}


if ($userfb==null) {



    $args = array('scope' => 'email');

    echo "<tr>";

    echo '<td><a href="' . $facebook->getLoginUrl($args) . '"><img src="fblogin.png" border="0" width="60" height="20"></a></td>';


    echo "</tr>";



 }
```

Comment: Check your app account on Facebook. Many apps needed changes due to Facebook's API changing. You might have some messages in your app on Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

All facebook tokens expire at some point (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) but if your users have authorized the app, you can have the Facebook SDK regenerate an access token within your catch block.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, unfortunately there is no message in mz app on Facebook. I also tried to delete the application on the facebook and create it again, but it did not help. How can I have the SDK regenerate an access token within the catch block please?

Comment: if you get an authorization exception, simply redirect back to your login with fb page.  That way the token will be reinitialized by fb and your app can continue to function normally.

Comment: Thank you, I might be stupid, but what exactly do you mean by "redirect back to your login with fb page"? What should I do please? Thanks a lot

Comment: You can use this method https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/ to redirect to facebook from your exception block (after you confirm that the exception is indeed an authException (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/exception-getType/). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks NullHappens, but it did not work either. I checked via facebook tools debugger the user token which is passed in the url of getLoginUrl as well as application token and both are ok. No matter if I am logged in FB or not, it always shows "Invalid access_token" and I see an error_code 100 in the url. I will give it some time else I will remove FB login from the page, it is exhausting - in general, all APIs should be easy to use and not forcing one to spend  hours of investigation when it stops to work :-( But thanks anyway